# How to destroy Ionic Component on redirect

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I have Ionic 4 Angular app. It has a three-tab structure. The tabs router module looks like this:

```
{
    path: 'tab1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../tab1/tab1.module').then((m) => m.Tab1PageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'tab2',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../tab2/tab2.module').then((m) => m.Tab2PageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../tab3/tab3.module').then((m) => m.Tab3PageModule),
  }
```

On each tab I have different components which I want to be destroyed by a redirect to another tab. But the Component destroy event doesn't happen.

In my case **Tab1** has this list:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item routerLink="invites">Invites</ion-item>
    <ion-item>Friend Requests</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

'Invites' click takes me to the **InvitesComponent**. After that, if I click Tab2 **InvitesComponent** will stay there in its latest state. When I click Tab1 back I expect to see the default **Tab1** screen but instead I meet by **InvitesComponent** *opened*.

I need somehow to destroy all child components by redirect events. I've already looked for (but no results):

1. How to destroy angular component by redirect
2. How to destroy angular component manually (programmatically)
3. Any types of 'Refs' that could
   be injected to represent current component entity (to call destroy()
   manually)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the **Tab1** button was not redirecting me straight to ***/tabs/tab1***. On initial click it is ***/tabs/tab1***. But after **InvitectComponent** was once opened the next Tab1 clicks redirected me to ***/tabs/tab1/invites***. Which still surprises me. So I've just added a slash symbol before tab attribute and that helped. Can anyone explain why is that so?

```
 <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="/tab1">
          <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
    
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
          <ion-icon name="film-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
    
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
          <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
```

In the end, I removed default Ionic tabs components and used buttons with routerOutlet instead

```
<ion-button routerLink="/tabs/tab1">
  <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>

<ion-button routerLink="/tabs/tab2">
  <ion-icon name="film-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>

<ion-button routerLink="/tabs/tab3">
  <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```